# Pre-order, активация

Tags: woocommerce

Ещё ни разу не приходилось использовать pre-order, а сейчас появилась задача добавить это на сайт. Подскажите, для чего вообще нужен pre-order и где его активировать?
В настройках нигде нет где бы можно было настроить pre-order.
Если есть ссылки почитать, желательно на русском пожалуйста, пока что не нашёл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На будущее - алгоритм поиска ответов на подобные вопросы :)

Что такое Pre-order? Смотрим в онлайн-словаре и видим, что это "предварительный заказ", или "предзаказ".

Если и это непонятно, то набираем в Гугле "предзаказ" и видим определение:

> Предварительный заказ или предзаказ — изъявление потребителем
>   намерения приобрести тот или иной товар. Предварительный заказ
>   позволяет потребителю заранее гарантированно закрепить за собой копию
>   этого товара.

Применительно к интернет-магазину это означает, например, что можно зарезервировать товар, которого на данный момент нет на складе, и когда он появится, покупателю придет уведомление.

Далее вбиваем в Гугл "предзаказ woocommerce" и первые же ссылки дают нам решение.

> Чтобы сделать предзаказ на Woocommerce, перейдите на страницу
>   «Товары». Под названием товара нажмите на вкладку «Свойства».
>
> Далее, в свойствах товара, внизу, для параметра «Предзаказы»,
>   установите значение «Разрешить» или «Разрешить, но уведомить клиента».
>
> Всё готово! Для товара будет доступен предзаказ.

http://info-effect.ru/sdelat-predzakaz-na-woocommerce.html

Comment: а как вывести на товаре что-то на подобие метки, указывающая, что товар относится к pre-order?

Comment: 2. При установленной опции "Разрешить, но уведомлять клиента" для "Разрешить предзаказы?" на странице товара, если товара не хватает будет сообщение "Доступно для предзаказа" и товар можно положить в корзину и купить.
После оформления заказа в письме у клиента будет отмечено какое количество товара находится в предзаказе.
Администратору приходит письмо, что товара нет на складе.

3. При установленной опции "Разрешить" для "Разрешить предзаказы?" клиент не будет знать, что товара нет.
Администратор также получает письмо о том, что заказанного товара нет на складе.

Comment: благодарю за информацию. Хотелось уточнить: в вёрстке на товаре стоит метка с надписью "pre-order". Как нужно в коде это сделать, чтобы на товаре была метка, ну или ярлык какой-то, указывающий на pre-order? т.е. при просмотре товаров, не в админке, а во фронтенде, на товаре есть эта метка

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, эта метка - как раз сообщение "Доступно для предзаказа" на странице товара. Все это работает, когда стоит галочка "Включить управление запасами на уровне товаров".

Comment: так а как вывести эту метку, какой код отвечает за это?